# Javascript помогите!

Tags: javascript

Я совсем не шарю в Java, в ответ прошу уже переделанный скрипт.
Тема такая: делаю скрипт для chrome браузера(консоль), нужен для автоклика по ссылкам (классу, точнее). С помощью шаманов с ютуба смог написать вот этот скрипт:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mainbut twitter');
for (var i = 0; i<elements.length;i++)
{
if ((elements[i].textContent) == "follow") elements[i].click();
}
```

Мне нужно внедрить в этот скрипт таймаут (паузу, грубо говоря) что бы при каждом нажатии на ссылку скрипт делал паузу, а не ждал после нажития на все ссылки.
Пробовал взять всё в функцию и привязать к ней .setTimeout,Interval, но не помогает, так как делает паузу после либо до произведения всех кликов.
Грубо говоря, скрипт прожимает все ссылки за минуту (без ожидания), а потом только ждет. Мне не вариант, забанят меня.
Помогите люди добрые.

Comment: Допустим, вы не шарите в Java. Но как у Вас дела с javascript?

Comment: Комрад, выдает такую ошибку:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined
    at delayedAction (<anonymous>:7:77)
    at a.bugsnag (bugsnag-2.min.js:1)
    at bugsnag-2.min.js:1

Comment: упс, секундочку. Проблема в том, что на момент выполнения i = length. Это дело надо замыкать. Лучшее решение на сегодня: `let el = elements[i]`

Comment: Спасибо, всё заработало.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете ставить функции в равномерно распределённую во времени очередь.

Данный пример назначает исполнение каждого последующего действия на 200ms позже во времени:

```
let lastActionDelay = 0;
const delayedAction = fn => setTimeout(fn, lastActionDelay+=200);

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mainbut twitter');
for (var i = 0; i<elements.length;i++)
{
  let el = elements[i];
  if ((el.textContent) == "follow") {
    delayedAction(() => el.click());
  }
}
```